# Анимация не показывается

Tags: java

Пытаюсь освоить анимацию на Java. По книге, которую я читаю в примере анимация запускается без использования кнопок. Я захотел запускать движение при помощи кнопки, но в результате программа показывает только начальное и конечное положение.

Код программы

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class SimpleGui3 implements ActionListener{

JFrame frame;
MyDrawPanel drawPanel;
Graphics2D g2d;


// Declare coordinates of circle
int x;
int y;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleGui3 gui= new SimpleGui3();
    gui.go();   
}

public void go(){

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // create button, which launch displesement of circle
    JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    start.addActionListener(this);

    // Declare graphic panel
    drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, start);
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            // Create a circle with random gradient color
            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

            red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

            GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70, 70, startColor, 150, 150, endColor);
            g2d.setPaint(gradient);
            g2d.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            x ++;
            y ++;
            drawPanel.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            }catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
    }

}
```

К тому же после завершения программы появляется кнопка вверху окна. Помогите разобраться в проблеме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я захотел запускать движение при помощи кнопки, но в результате
>   программа показывает только начальное и конечное положение.

Вы запускаете перерисовку компонентов в потоке диспетчеризации и до окончания исполнения цикла поток будет занят. Следовательно отобразится сразу конечная картинка без промежуточных. В вашем случае следует запускать отдельный поток, в котором и будет производиться изменение координат и отметка компонента как требующего перерисовку методом repaint().

> К тому же после завершения программы появляется кнопка вверху окна.

Это следствие того, что вы не вызываете родительский метод paintComponent() в котором отрисовывается остальные части компонента. Следует в начале метода вызывать super.paintComponent(g), а уже после, поверх результата рисовать то, что вам требуется.

Итого с учетом вышесказанного:

Код метода paintComponent:

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); // добавлено
            g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            // Create a circle with random gradient color
            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

            red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

            GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70, 70, startColor, 150, 150, endColor);
            g2d.setPaint(gradient);
            g2d.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);
}
```

Код actionPerformed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                x ++;
                y ++;
                drawPanel.repaint();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(25);
                }catch(Exception ex) {}
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```